# hi i got error on pop up modal using jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, vb.net, asp-classic

When i try to create new page  in asp . The error always pop up.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  BlockUI("<%=pnlAddEdit.ClientID %>");  
});
```

Error : `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #<%=pnlAddEdit.ClientID %>`

File: `jquery-1.11.2.min.js, Line: 2, Column: 12711`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  BlockUI('<%=pnlAddEdit.ClientID %>');  
});
```

`""` makes it a string value and does not evaluate the expression. It should ideally work if you change it to `''`

Comment: no i just delete it hahaha ... next time i will keep it mind